# Why gives the undefinded index error?

Tags: php, undefined-index

```
if(isset($_POST['dino_c']) AND isset($_POST['dino_box']) AND isset($dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$_POST['dino_box']])){
if(....){
if(($pop>(0-1+$dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$_POST['dino_box']][4])) AND ($resource[0]>(0-1+$dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][5] -1)) AND ($resource[1]>(0-1+$dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][6] -1)) AND ($resource[2]>(0-1+$dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][7] -1))){
.
.
.
.
$pop = $pop - $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$_POST['dino_box']][4];
$pop_consum = $pop_consum + $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$_POST['dino_box']][4];
$resource[0] = 0 + $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][5];
$resource[1] = 0 + $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][6];
$resource[2] = 0 + $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][7];
$dino_add[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]-1] = 0 + $dino_recruit[$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][1]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_c']][3]][$a_dino[$_POST['dino_box']]][0];
.
.
.
.
}
}
}
```

It's my code and when I use it :

```
> undefined index:4 in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index: in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index:4 in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index: in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index:4 in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index: in .... ajax.php on line 672  => here line 3
> undefined index:4 in .... ajax.php on line 679  => here line 10
> undefined index: in .... ajax.php on line 679  => here line 10
....
> undefined index:4 in .... ajax.php on line 682  => here line 13
> undefined index: in .... ajax.php on line 682  => here line 13
```

I use isset() to check my data. if all is set why produces an error?

in this code we have 2 $_POST and they are checked in line 1 and other data is array and I check it 100 time and I do not see where is error.
Please see lines 8 and 9. They do not have error. Although the structure is similar to other lines.Why?

Comment: undefined index:[...] the tree dots is where the error says wich index is undifine

Comment: Without looking at it ... are all those $a_dino[$_POST['xyz']] and alike set? If NOT, you have to check them with isset() also. Show us the line of code where the error occurs.

Comment: ok edited and I add all error. and now?

Comment: Well, it tells you loud and clear, the problems is where u use number 4 as index...

Comment: ya, I know. `$_POST['dino_box'] = 4` and I use it in all line but in line 8 & 9 we don't have an error. why? I sure that all data is set ...

Answer (score 4):

When u do `isset($r['t']['b']['v']);`

It assumes `$r['t']['b']` already exists, and checks only the `['v']`.
If those `['t']` or `['b']` are none existent PHP will emit a warning, even if it is inside `isset`

So to check such multiple dim array is actually:

```
if(isset($r['t'])&&isset($r['t']['b'])&&isset($r['t']['b']['v'])){...
```

Comment: ty for answer. but all is set.I check it 100 time. they are array and data form database. do you need to see array?

Comment: `isset` checks if the variable is defined. If i check something like `var_dump( isset($undefinedVar[1][2][3]) );` it will return false not the warnings. Can you provide some clear example that explains your point "It assumes $r['t']['b'] already exists, and checks only the ['v']. If those ['t'] or ['b'] are none existent PHP will emit a warning, even if it is inside isset".